# Maxima: How to force numerical evaluation

Tags: maxima

I have defined

```
log10(x) := log(x) / log(10);
ndigits(x) := fix(log10(x) + 1);
```

When I try to apply `ndigits` to a value I seem unable to get a numerical result:

```
(%i18) NDIGITS(1);
(%o18)                            NDIGITS(1)
(%i19) float(NDIGITS(1));
(%o19)                           NDIGITS(1.0)
```

How can I get a numerical result here?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, well. I don't know why the Maxima command line autocompletes in uppercase, but Maxima *is* casesensitive:

```
(%i45) ndigits(1);
(%o45) 

                            1
```